# Widening From Byte to Int (Marshmallow bug)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Sorry in advance for the long question but everything should be straight forward and clear what's going on, thanks for taking a look. Please note that this is not actually code, just pseudo code to understand the application's implementation.

> **Issue**

Byte's aren't widening to the true numerical value. Note: `level = -1` represents a game that hasn't started. `level == 24` represents the end of the game.

Class 1

```
private byte level = -1;
private byte stage = 0;

@NonNull private final Stages[][] stages = new Stages[25][13];

public byte getLevel () {
   return level;
}  

public void nextLevel () {
// expect: 0 
   level++;

// stages[  128][    0] (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds)
   stages[level][stage] = new Stage();
}
```

Class 2 extends Class 1

```
@NonNull private final byte[][] values = new byte[25][4];

public byte getScore (final byte level, final byte player) {
   //     values[  255][     2] (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds)
   return values[level][player];
}

// expecting: -1  >= 0 (false)
// runtime:   255 >= 0 (true)
if (Class1.getLevel() >= 0)
    getScore(Class1.getLevel(), 2);
```

> **Binary**

8 bit (byte)

```
-1   == 1111 1111
-128 == 1000 0000
 127 == 0111 1111
```

32 bit (integer)

```
-1   == 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
 127 == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1111
 128 == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000
 255 == 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

> **What Worked**

Using the wrapper class

```
public Byte level = -1;
```

> **Question**

I understand the issue is the number's binary representation is being used directly when it widens from byte to int. My number is literally going from 8 bit `1111 1111` to 32 bit `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111`. My question is why doesn't Java (or why is it not in this situation/environment) convert the number to the true numerical value when widening instead of just padding zeros to the raw binary representation.

This appears to only be happening to negative numbers, I assume because positive numbers have the same bit representation before and after widening.

Why isn't my number going from 8 bit `1111 1111` to 32 bit `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`? Why is the postfix increment creating a value of 128..? Is there a better solution to this issue beside the one I'm currently stuck with.?

I prefer not to just use that solution without knowing the underlining problem because the issue can quietly (run without errors) break my applications algorithm; So it is with much appreciation if someone can please explain this issue to me.

Thanks, Jay

> **Current Working Environment**

**JDK** 1.8.076

**OS** X El Capitan

**Android Studio** 2.2 Preview 2

**buildToolsVersion** '23.0.3'

**classpath** 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'

**Emulator** Nexus 6P API 23 x86

> **Conclusion**

I was able to narrow the issue to exclusively Android 23 (Marshmallow) devices. I have reported the bug to Google Inc. Thanks for everybody's help, I'll just give a warning to Android 23 (Marshmallow) user's as the bug doesn't appear in Android N, Android 22 and lower.

Comment: I think the reason is maybe not the bit representation, but the fact that you use the byte in an array index. This may change conversion rules. I tried to find facts in java language specs but could not find a hint yet. Can you try to assign the index values to local int before using them in the array index? Does it change sth?

Comment: I found a hint. Still need to understand clearly: In array index context, unary conversion is applied. The example shows that `byte b = -1; int i =-b; -> i=0!`.

Comment: Hi Jay, I tried your code now at home and it did run fine. I used JDK 1.8.044 and will try .77 and .91 (currently downloading). I could not download .76 for windows though. Have you checked for a Java update? Does this only happen in the Android emulator?

Comment: If this really is a runtime (marshmallow only) bug the JDK compile version shouldn't really matter. Let's assume this really is a bug, literally hundreds off apps would have to crash on marshmallow (I have not seen a single report claiming it happens). I suspect your code has side effects (threading, volatile memory?) which cause this behavior.

Comment: @Rolfツ The code works in Android N and Android 22 or lower. I don't use the field in any other thread

Answer (score 3):

why not translate signed bytes to unsigned?

```
public static int signedByteToInt(byte b) {
    return b & 0xFF;
}
```

to make sure for you here is samples of representation in signed byte:

```
-3 - 11111101
-2 - 11111110
-1 - 11111111
0  - 00000000
1  - 00000001
2  - 00000010
3  - 00000011
```

and when you use byte as int it java will in anyway represent this byte as signed one so from 11111111 (-1) you will get 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 (-1) and I dont see here any problems.

just keep in memory that:

```
from -1 to -128 is from 11111111 to 10000000
and from 0 to 127 is from 00000000 to 01111111
```

and make proper conversion when you use it as int.

so below zero representations are like backward counter to middle

and by the way this is not only in java )

here:

```
if (Class1.getLevel() >= 0)
```

you compare byte with integer, try to make:

```
if (Class1.getLevel() >= (byte)0)
```

and feel happy :)

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, I like it.  Trusting your memory of esoteric conversions is not the most productive way to spend your energy--instead force the issue.  Still, his question is valid--it's worth it to understand what's going on.

Comment: The samples you give should all work without explicit casting. The OP is using the fact that -1 + 1 is 0. This is not a byte issue, it will happen with int as well. The issue is, that in his case, the byte -1 is interpreted as int 127 and the result is suddenly 128. If you call `signedToUnsigned(level)+1` you will be exactly in the situation the op describes.

Answer (score 2):

Jay, I saw your code and I checked the documentation for the Java language.

To me, the behavior you describe is as follows:

```
private byte level = -1;
private byte stage = 0;
```

You initialize bytes to -1 and 0. 
Later, you call `nextLevel()` and expect it to init `stage[0][0]`, but instead, you receive a "out of bounds" exception. So, the first level is never reached.

```
public void nextLevel() {
// expect: 0
    level++;

// stages[  128][    0] (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds)
    stages[level][stage] = new Stage();
}
```

If the code you did not show in your sample does not create side effects producing the situation, the following code is a working sample, that should be sufficient to expose the issue:

```
package com.bytemagic;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

/**
 * Created by thst on 01.06.2016.
 */
public class ByteMagic {

    private class Stage {
    }

    private byte level = -1;
    private byte stage = 0;

    @NotNull
    private final Stage[][] stages = new Stage[25][13];

    public byte getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void nextLevel() {
    // expect: 0
        level++;

    // stages[  128][    0] (ArrayIndexOutOfBounds)
        stages[level][stage] = new Stage();
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
        ByteMagic me = new ByteMagic();

        me.nextLevel();
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(me.getLevel()));
    }
}
```

I tried this code with JDK8u66, JDK8u77. This does not expose any issue. 
The byte `level` will properly be increased to 0 and the `stages` is initializing properly.

Would you please try to run that code on your machine and setup? Is this code exposing the issue?

After all: `level` cannot hold 128, it can hold -128, but that is not what you describe.

`level++` will do all kinds of funny conversions. According to the docs, to calculate the increment, `1`, `level` are converted to integer with proper widening if required (so 0xff -> 0xffffffff), then 1 is added, resulting in 0x0 (int). This is then narrowed back to 0x0 (byte) and written to `level`. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

The array access is using a slightly different conversion rule. The array access requires the index to be of type integer. The conversion from byte to int uses unary numeric promotion rules, that can have interesting conversion effect when using unary minus, but for your case, with a byte value of `0`, nothing spectacular or unexpected will happen.

(For reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4 and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3)

So, I cannot reproduce the failure with the code samples given, and my suspicion goes into the direction that this is either some side effect of code I cannot see or it is a bug in the JDK you use or in the environment (Dalvik VM).